# Can't resolve symbol @android:drawable

Tags: android, xml, icons, drawable

I have a new icon in “drawable” folder. Following is the code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
```

But when I define it in drawable.xml, it points out:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@android:drawable/ic_menu_favorite' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.
```

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Have you tried using `@drawable` only without `@android:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@android:` refers to elements defined in the Android SDK. For instance, `@android:color/holo_red_dark` is set to `#ffcc0000`.

If you want to target your resources defined in the resource folders all you have to do is remove the `android` prefix and use directly `@drawable`, `@color`, etc.

Comment: Some tutorials add the android: prefix, because they use standard android icons. Why not explain too how to use your own? Grrnnn.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with Martin, I had the same problem following a tutorial!